# How to verify with Mockito that another public method of SUT was called during test

Tags: java, junit, kotlin, mockito

I am aware of duplicate, bo no answer about actual question was given there.

[How to verify if method is called on System under test (not a mock)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12429157/how-to-verify-if-method-is-called-on-system-under-test-not-a-mock)

I have a class:

```
class A {

    public long a() {
        if(something) {
            return quicklyCalculatedResult
        } else {
            return b() run on separate thread, with this one blocked
        }
    }

    public long b() {} //doStuffOnCurrentThread;

}
```

I have a complete set of tests for b(), which does the heavy lifting. Unfortunately I have to make an ugly think like a() (legacy code) and I don't want to copy all the tests. Of method b(). Also, both of these need to be public.

I want to verify that under certain circumstances a() calls b(), but I cannot do that, beacause tested class is not a mock. I need a way to verify that method was called on a real object, not only a mock.

Comment: IMHO, I don’t think you should worry if b gets called. Instead focus on the conditions that lead to b being called (the negative of ‘something’ conditional) and then verify that you get the results you expected. The point of mocking is to allow you to simplify/control your dependency/coupling to the classes not under test. Additionally, you should, even though you don’t want to, migrate the tests to focus on b that need to focus on b.

Comment: @JasonArmstrong Hey, this is a way but there are many many conditions that may lead to b() being called. In my real example it is more like "if some argument is null, then give a quick answer and in any other case get b()'s result". b() will response in a variety of ways, depending on given arguments. So to check this with returned value instead of checking if b() was called I would have to test multiple scenarios and this is basically copying b()'s tests...

Comment: I understand what you’re saying, but what are you really **unit** testing at that point a or b?

Comment: I want to unit test a(). And requirement for a is to "if some arguments are null then calculate something, other way call b()".

Comment: @JasonArmstrong While I agree with what you are saying in principle, there are times when we have to test difficult legacy code. That is what partial mocking was made for.

Comment: @Dean I hear you and I agree, sometimes we have to choose an undesirable path, I was just wanted to call attention to it so when others come see this question they can make an informed choice.

Comment: @JasonArmstrong Yes, you are right to do so.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mockito and other kotlin mocking libraries provide partial mocking or similar functionality. You can specify real methods to be called, while the other methods remain stubs:

Mockito java example:

```
A classUnderTest = mock(A.class);
when(classUnderTest.a()).thenCallRealMethod();

classUnderTest.a();
verify(classUnderTest).b()
```

See the mockito [Documentation](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.23.4/org/mockito/Mockito.html#16) on partial mocking. Partial mocking is not encouraged because it does not fit good OOP design, but in your case it fit its intended purpose, which is to test difficult legacy code.

Kotlin example with vanilla Mockito:

```
val classUnderTest = mock(A::class.java)
`when`(classUnderTest.a()).thenCallRealMethod()

classUnderTest.a()
verify(classUnderTest).b()
```

[mockito-kotlin](https://github.com/nhaarman/mockito-kotlin) provides extensions that allow you to use mockito in a more kotlin idiomatic way. Unfortunately there does not appear to be a way to do partial mocking in a kotlin idiomatic way, but it can be achieved in mockito-kotlin like so:

```
val classUnderTest = mock<A>()
doCallRealMethod().whenever(classUnderTest).a()

classUnderTest.a()
verify(classUnderTest).b()
```

[MockK](https://mockk.io/), an idiomatic kotlin mocking library, allows for this functionality with spys. After creating a `spy` of the class you can choose to stub methods:

```
val classUnderTest = spyk<A>()
every { classUnderTest.b() } returns 1L

classUnderTest.a()
verify { classUnderTest.b() }
```

Comment: Hey, thanks! I had little troubles making it work, but only because of using Kotlin instead of Java. It is exactly what I needed :)

Answer (score 2):

You can make `A` a spy with [`@Spy`](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.23.4/org/mockito/Spy.html) or `Mockito.spy()`. This will allow you to invoke and test `a()` method logic but also replace `b()` with an invariant. This can be illustrated with a list:

```
List list = new LinkedList();
List spy = Mockito.spy(list);

// Impossible: real method is called so spy.get(0) throws IndexOutOfBoundsException (the list is yet empty)
when(spy.get(0)).thenReturn("foo");

// You have to use doReturn() for stubbing
doReturn("foo").when(spy).get(0);
```

Comment: Thanks! It works and I voted up. I gave correct answer to @Dean because his answer was closer to question and for bringing up .thenCallRealMethod(), but your way works as well!